# "Non-medium error" in smartctl output

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl

Who can explain what is meaning "Non-medium error" in this output.

I think my hard disks have some problems.

**Disk1**

```
root@nshost2:/home/david # smartctl -a -d cciss,0 /dev/ciss0 
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p4 amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HP
Product:              EH0146FARWD
Revision:             HPDC
User Capacity:        146,815,737,856 bytes [146 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Rotation Rate:        15030 rpm
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000cca00b7b4c54
Serial number:        PLX5U32E
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Mon Aug 15 16:37:17 2016 AMT
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     28 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        65 C

Manufactured in week 05 of year 2012
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  50000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  31
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 18233185821261824

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:          0   168255         0    168255          0      21908.836           0
write:         0  5365037         0   5365037          0      46145.893           0

Non-medium error count:      691

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background short  Completed                   -       7                 - [-   -    -]
# 2  Background short  Completed                   -       3                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self Test duration: 1394 seconds [23.2 minutes]
```

**Disk2**

```
root@nshost2:/home/david # smartctl -a -d cciss,1 /dev/ciss0
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p4 amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HP
Product:              EH0146FARWD
Revision:             HPDC
User Capacity:        146,815,737,856 bytes [146 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Rotation Rate:        15030 rpm
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000cca00b7b2254
Serial number:        PLX5R9BE
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Mon Aug 15 16:38:56 2016 AMT
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     26 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        65 C

Manufactured in week 05 of year 2012
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  50000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  31
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 18232624858267648

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:          0   204138         0    204138          0      21981.509           0
write:         0  3646624         0   3646624          0      46146.250           0

Non-medium error count:      693

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background short  Completed                   -       7                 - [-   -    -]
# 2  Background short  Completed                   -       3                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self Test duration: 1394 seconds [23.2 minutes]
```

**Here is cciss output**

```
root@nshost2:/home/david # cciss_vol_status -q /dev/ciss0
/dev/ciss0: (Smart Array P410i) RAID 1(1+0) Volume 0 status: OK.
```

Comment: According to the [wiki](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/www/smartmontools_scsi.xml#errorlog) it's the "number of recoverable events other than write, read or verify errors".  Those seem to be hardware errors.  I'm not sure exactly of what nature those might be, but my educated guess is that you probably aren't going to lose your data in the near future, but it might still be a good idea to start shopping for a new disk, particularly if that number is increasing.

Comment: according to [this](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xfamera/blog/) it counts number of communication errors and errors in disk electronics